# mysqldump waiting for table fush for long time

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, mysql-8.0

MySQL version: MySQL Commercial 8.0.16 OS: RHEL 7.6

Following is my mysqldump command

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/mysql_data/config/extra_options.cnf --single-transaction --flush-logs --master-data=2 --dump-date --max-allowed-packet=64M  --events --routines --all-databases >  all-databases_`date +%F`.sql
```

When I issued `show full processlist;`, I found out that the mysqldump is `waiting for table flush`

There is one job that keeps running on the server which keeps two tables open.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID , CARD_NUMBER , RRN_NUMBER , GROSS_TENURE , ADVANCE_EMI , POS_ENTRY_MODE , NO_OF_ADVANCE_EMI , MODE_OF_TRANSACTION , SOURCE_OF_TRANSACTION , RESPONSE_CODE , DECLINE_REASON_DESCRIPTION , FAILED_RULE_ID , NOW_AVAILABLE_LIMIT , BEFORE_TXN_AVAILABLE_LIMIT , OPEN_ECS_AVAILABLE_EMI_LIMIT_C , OPEN_ECS_VALID_DATE_C , CIBIL_TRIGGERED_ID , PRICING_CALCULATED_FEE , NO_LIVE_LOANS_DIGI , NO_LIVE_LOANS_REMI , NO_LIVE_LOANS_ECOM , NO_LIVE_LOANS_NONDIGI , NO_LIVE_LOANS_REP , NO_LIVE_LOANS_EPL , NO_LIVE_LOANS_SPL , NO_LIVE_LOANS_ERL , NO_LIVE_LOANS_WLT , NO_LIVE_LOANS_RWT , NO_LOANS_EVER_DIGI , NO_LOANS_EVER_REMI , NO_LOANS_EVER_ECOM , NO_LOANS_EVER_NONDIGI , DEALER_CODE_ETAILER , DEALER_FORMAT , EMI_AMT , TOTAL_EMI_LIVE_LOANS_ALL , TOTAL_EMI_LIVE_LOANS_ECF , TOTAL_EMI_LIVE_LOANS_ERF , TOTAL_EMI_LIVE_LOANS_REMI , TOTAL_EMI_LIVE_LOANS_DIGI , TOTAL_EMI_LIVE_LOANS_NONDIGI , CARD_UTILIZATION_ACCOUNT , CARD_UTILIZATION_CUSTOMER , HIGHEST_UTILIZATION_L6M , NO_OF_NON_TECH_BOUNCE_12M_ALL_LOANS , NO_OF_NON_TECH_BOUNCE_6M_ALL_LOANS , NO_NONTECH_BNC_L3M , NO_BNC_L12M , DAYS_DIFF_BASELOAN , HAS_HL_BUREAU , HAS_CC_BUREAU , BUREAU_TIMESERIES_SEG , MBK_DNLD_DT_STATUS , DEALER_RANK , DEALER_CITY_ID , DEALER_PINCODE , DEALER_STATE , CUSTOMER_PINCODE , CUSTOMER_STATE , INTERCITY_TRXN , MBL_CHANGE_DATE , DAYS_DIFF_MBLCHNG , CIBILSCORE , CARD_TYPE , CUSTOMER_TYPE , CARD_SOURCE_IDENTIFIER , ASSET_CATEGORY , DAYS_FROM_LAST_CIBIL , ASSET_CATEGORY_RISK_HIGH_MEDIUM_LOW , PRODUCT , LTV , DAYS_FROM_CARD_VALID_DATE , DAYS_FROM_LAST_LOAN , B_SCORE , DAYS_FROM_LAST_TRANSACTION , NET_LOAN_AMOUNT , VALIDFROM_C_CUSTOMER_LEVEL , LAST_CIBIL_DATE_C , NO_OF_ACTIVE_LOANS_C , PROCESS_DEVIATION_FLAG , SMT_FLAG , HML_TAG , LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_RESIDENCE_EMAIL , LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_OFFICE_MOBILE_NO , LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_RESIDENCE_ADDRESS , LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_OFFICE_ADDRESS , ORIGINAL_AUTH_AMOUNT , PERTNER_EDC_CHANNEL , FRAUD_FLAG , CIBIL_THICK_THIN , LINE_MULTIPLIER , COMPUTED_LIMIT , DEALER_TYPE , BLOCK_CODE_SYSTEM , CARD_DESIGN , DEALER_SUPER_GROUP , PRICING_OVL_LINE_AMOUNT , PRICING_OVL_LINE_CONSUMPTION , PRICING_OVL_PCNT_CONSUMPTION , AUTH_REQUEST_DATE_TIME , CHAMPAIGN_CHALLENGER_NAME , CUSTOMER_CITY_ID , CARD_LIMIT , TOTAL_NET_ACTIVE_LOAN , TRANSACTION_STATUS , VOID_DATE , CONVENIENCE_FEE , CONVENIENCE_FEE_CHARGE_ID , CHARGE_FEE , CHARGE_ID , PRICING_FEE_CHARGE_ID , SHADOW_LIMIT , SHADOW_LIMIT_CONSUMPTION , DELIVERY_PIN_CODE , NO_OF_APPR_TXNS_DONE_ON_CARD_SAME_DAY , NO_OF_REJ_TXNS_DONE_ON_CARD_SAME_DAY , NO_OF_TXNS_DONE_ON_CARD_SAME_DAY , DAYS_DIFF_MBLCHNG , CARDS_CUSTOMER_IDS_MARKED_RISKY_IN_ATOS , PRIOR_FAILED_TRANSACTION_ON_THE_SAME_DAY_DUE_TO_OTP_EXPIRY , MULT_TXNS_ON_CARD_ON_SAME_DAY_TOT_AMT_GREATER_THAN_30000 , OTHER_TXN_TYPE_ON_THE_SAME_DAY , TRANSACTION_DONE_ON_INTERSTATE_DEALER , DELIVERY_ADDRESS_CHANGE_FLAG , NO_OF_CARDS_LINKED_TO_MOBILE , ADDON_CARD_FLAG , ASSET_TYPE , ORDER_NUMBER_ECOM_PARTNER , EMAIL_ID , LAST_APPROVED_TRANSACTION_DATE , DOB , RESIDENCE_MOBILE_NUMBER_C , OFFICE_MOBILE_NUMBER_C , DELER_NAME_C , CUSTOMER_RESIDENCE_CITY_C , CUSTOMER_STATE_C , DEALER_CITY_C , DEALER_STATE_C , OLD_MOBILENUMBER , FOS_MOBILE FROM db1.transaction_details WHERE RESPONSE_CODE = '00' AND RRN_NUMBER NOT IN ( SELECT RRN FROM db1.JOB_PROCESSING ) LIMIT 1000
```

This query runs for almost 12 seconds and runs every minute.

```
root@localhost > show open tables where in_use > 0;
+----------+--------------------------+--------+-------------+
| Database | Table                    | In_use | Name_locked |
+----------+--------------------------+--------+-------------+
| db1      | job_processing           |      1 |           0 |
| db1      | transaction_details      |      1 |           0 |
+----------+--------------------------+--------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

The tables are not very big in size.

```
root@localhost> select table_name, (data_length+index_length)/1024/1024 from information_schema.tables where table_name in('transaction_details','job_processing');
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME               | (data_length+index_length)/1024/1024 |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| job_processing           |                           5.04687500 |
| transaction_details      |                          38.14062500 |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

The row count is as follows

```
root@localhost> select count(*) from job_processing;
    +----------+
    | count(*) |
    +----------+
    |    13525 |
    +----------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)

root@localhost> select count(*) from transaction_details;

    +----------+
    | count(*) |
    +----------+
    |    15369 |
    +----------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Is this happening because the tables are open? The mysqldump option `--single-transaction` performs a flush tables with read lock and is it waiting for the queries to close the tables?** State "`Waiting for table flush`" in processlist

MySQL Docs says "How MySQL Opens and Closes Tables"

MySQL is multi-threaded, so there may be many clients issuing queries for a given table simultaneously. To minimize the problem with multiple client sessions having different states on the same table, the table is opened independently by each concurrent session. This uses additional memory but normally increases performance. With MyISAM tables, one extra file descriptor is required for the data file for each client that has the table open. (By contrast, the index file descriptor is shared between all sessions.)

**What should I do in this case? Please help.**

I keep physical backups as well using Enterprise Backup, but the company policy requires me to maintain both the backups and once I see 'waiting for table flush', all the subsequent queries get stuck with 'waiting for table flush'. Thus, sometimes the backup fails.

`UNLOCK TABLES` does not help. `One thing I do is I kill the query, the above mentioned job and after sometime things are fine.`

Comment: What did the `Time` column of PROCESSLIST say when it was "waiting"?

Comment: Run `SHOW OPEN TABLES;`

Comment: The TIME was almost 500 or something like that. SHOW OPEN TABLES output is in the question.

Comment: The only thing I could do was kill the running job, and re-initiate the dump.

Answer (score 0):

Slow query?  Let's speed it up;

Instead of

```
    FROM  db1.transaction_details
    WHERE  RESPONSE_CODE = '00'
      AND  RRN_NUMBER NOT IN (
        SELECT  RRN
            FROM  db1.JOB_PROCESSING 
                          )
    LIMIT  1000
```

say

```
    FROM  db1.transaction_details AS td
    LEFT JOIN db1.JOB_PROCESSING AS jp
             ON td.RRN_NUMBER = jp.RRN
    WHERE  RESPONSE_CODE = '00'
      AND  jp.RRN  IS NULL
    LIMIT  1000
```

or

```
    FROM  db1.transaction_details AS td
    WHERE  RESPONSE_CODE = '00'
      AND  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                        FROM  db1.JOB_PROCESSING 
                        WHERE RRN = td.RRN_NUMBER )
    LIMIT  1000
```

(Different versions of MySQL and MariaDB optimize these 3 variants differently; I can't predict which is fastest.)

`transaction_details` needs an index starting with `RESPONSE_CODE`.

`JOB_PROCESSING` needs an index starting with `RRN`.

If those things don't speed it up enough, we can work on pushing the `LIMIT` into a derived table that delivers only the PK of `td`.

**Push LIMIT down**

How fast does this run by itself?

```
SELECT id    -- just the PRIMARY KEY
    FROM  db1.transaction_details
    WHERE  RESPONSE_CODE = '00'
      AND  RRN_NUMBER NOT IN (
        SELECT  RRN
            FROM  db1.JOB_PROCESSING 
                             )
    LIMIT  1000;
```

If reasonably fast, then see how the following works:

```
SELECT lots-of-stuff
    FROM ( the-above-query ) AS x
    JOIN db1.transaction_details AS td
        USING(id);   -- again the PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: Thanks Mr James, the LEFT JOIN optimisation took almost 46 minutes, and the second optimisation took almost 8 while the original query was executed in 6 minutes. And yes, the said indexes are already there on the table.

Comment: @AvinashPawar - Ouch.

Comment: @AvinashPawar - Eh?  The Question mentions "12 seconds"; your comment says "6 minutes"??

Comment: @AvinashPawar - and see if the new formulation helps any.

Comment: When the job was executed during the initial setup there was not much data in the table and then it took 12 seconds (or may be I missed something), now there is a lot data in the transaction_details table. I will try the suggestions and post the results.

Comment: Pushing limit down -- First query took 9 minutes :-( and then the next modification took 8 minutes :-). Is it weird?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101577/discussion-between-avinash-pawar-and-rick-james).

Comment: What if I remove the --flush-logs options from the mysqldump command? FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK is not by --single-transaction I guess, but because of --flush-logs option.